# Running a Specific Test from a Set of Data Driven Tests in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tdd, data-driven-tests

Does anyone know if it's possible to run a specific test in Visual Studio from a set of data driven tests (i.e. using the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting library)? At the moment I'm having to use conditional breakpoints and test debugging, which I'm finding alittle bit of a pain.